# Inequality concerning trace of the product of symmetric positive matrices

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let $S$ and $H$ be symmetric positive definite (spd), I have to prove that:

$$ \sqrt[n]{\det{S}}\leq\frac{Tr(SH)}{n\sqrt[n]{\det{H}}}$$

---

I have already proven that there exists $T$ spd such that $T^2=S$ and that $SH$ is similar to $THT$ and therefore is spd too.
I have also noted that the roots of the determinants are simply the geometric means of the eigenvalues, but have not been able to translate the trace of the product over $n$ into anything meaningful...

I have tried using the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means, but it doesn't really apply since there are two geometric means.

Comment: I have a hunch that $Tr(SH)=s_1h_1+...+s_nh_n$ when denoting $s_i$ and $h_i$ their eigenvalues.
Then, $\frac{Tr(SH)}{n\sqrt[n]{det(H)}}\geq\frac{s_1h_1+...+s_nh_n}{h_1+...+h_n}$ which feels close to the result, given that $h_i>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$SH$ is similar to the symmetric positive definite matrix $R=S^{1/2}HS^{1/2}$.

The identity to be proven is equivalent to

$$\sqrt[n]{\det{R}}  \leq \frac{Tr(R)}{n}$$ as $\det{R} = \det{SH} = \det{S}\det{H}$.

$\sqrt[n]{\det{R}}$ is equal to the geometric mean of $R$ eigenvalues (counted with multiplicity). $\frac{Tr(R)}{n}$ is equal to the arithmetic mean of $R$ eigenvalues.

The inequality is therefore a consequence of the fact that geometric mean is less or equal to arithmetic mean.

Comment: I think this has to be the closest I ever was to solving a question without success... Thanks!

Comment: Follow-up question: show that $\sqrt[n]{det(S)}$ is actually the infimum of the previous quantity over all spd matrices.
I've tried a hundred different ways, but all I have shown is that it isn't necessarily reached.

Comment: I'm not sure if the product $SH$ is symmetric. I feel like this method works in the case of a single matrix but not in the case of th product.

Comment: @rubikscube09 Unfortunately... you are right. I’ll have to revise my answer.

Comment: Your idea works if you replace $AB$ with $AB(AB)^T$ and do some manipulations with the trace

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Actually, on second thought, why is symmetry needed? I thought it would be enough if both matrices were PD.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B$ be symmetric, positive definite matrices. The main issue in proving this inequality is that the product $AB$ is not necessarily symmetric, as we need the symmetry to conclude that (??? not sure here why symmetry is needed). In any case, consider the matrix $AB (AB)^\dagger$ where the $\dagger$ denotes the Hermitian conjugate. Now, we have that:
$$
\mathrm{Tr}(AB(AB)^\dagger) = \mathrm{Tr}(ABB^\dagger A^\dagger) = \mathrm{Tr}(ABBA)=  \mathrm{Tr}(AABB) = \mathrm{Tr}((AB)^2)
$$
with the last few manipulations coming from the fact that $A,B$ are Hermitian, and that the trace is invariant under cyclic permutation. Now, $(AB)^2$ is positive definite and Hermitian, so by the spectral theorem, the square root of $AB$ is also symmetric and also positive definite. Applying standard AM-GM argument + the multiplicativity of the determinant nets us the inequality we need.